# Prove the matrix is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> For any reals, $a, b$ show that
>
> $$D = \begin{bmatrix}
> a & 1\\ 
> 0 &  b
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   Is **not** diagonalizable.

I got that the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = a, \lambda_2 = b$

However, for $a \ne b$, there are $2$ distinct eigenvalues so $D$ must be diagonalizable right?

So what about $a= b$?

Comment: You are correct.  If $a\neq b$ then it is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 5):

In the case where $a = b$, we have only one eigenvalue $\lambda = a$. In order for the matrix to be diagonalisable, the algebraic multiplicity (let's denote it $\mu$) of the eigenvalue $\lambda$, where $\mu = 2$ in our example, **must** be equal to its geometric multiplicity $\gamma.$

We know by definition that $ \gamma = \dim \ker (D-\lambda I),$ with $$\ker (D-\lambda I) = \{ x \in \mathbb R^2: (D-\lambda I)x = 0\}.$$
However:
$$D-\lambda I = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0  \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$

We can easily notice that $\operatorname{rank} (D-\lambda I) = 1 \implies \dim \ker (D-\lambda I) = \gamma = 1$ (according to the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)).

Thus, we have that $2 = \mu \neq \gamma = 1.$ Thus, whenever $a=b( = k)$, matrix $D$ is **not** diagonalisable, regardless the value of $k$.

Comment: Can one of $a$ or $b$ be zero?

Comment: @ThomasRasberry As stated above in the comment, if $a\neq b$ then $A$ is diagonalisable, regardless the values of $a,b.$  If $a=b=0$,then $A$ is not diagonalisable.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\mathbf{A} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & 1 \\
 0 & b \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Eigenvalues
$$
\lambda \left( \mathbf{A} \right) = (a, b)
$$
Eigenvectors:
$$
v_{1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0
\end{array}
\right), \qquad
v_{2} =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 b-a
\end{array}
\right)
$$

(Good point by @Joonas Ilmavirta.)

Comment: You could write your second eigenvector as $v_2=(1,b-a)$. It's an eigenvector, no matter what $a$ and $b$ are. This only makes the issue change form: $v_1=v_2$ when $a=b$.